# window service installation issues

Tags: .net, service, window

i have a problem in installation of a window service using c#. when i created my first project of window service i got the following issue:
"Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A windows Service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Afministrative tool or the NET START command".

then i edited my program.cs as:

```
    static void Main()
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        Service1 service = new Service1();
        string[] args = new string[] { "arg1", "arg2" };
        service.StartFromDebugger(args);
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}

// Also added the following code
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public void StartFromDebugger(string[] args)
    {
        OnStart(args);
    }

}
```

then this problem was resolved. after that when i create .exe file of that project by adding new setup project and install it on my system then it gives me the above error again.
plz help me....thanx in advance

Comment: It's not the direct answer, but try [top-shelf](http://topshelf-project.com). It allows you to build and debug windows services much more easier.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to install your service is  as following:

Go to CMD and run it as an Administrator

write down this command ::

```
sc create  YourServiceName displayname= "Service Name to be displayed" binpath= c:\YourService.exe start= demand
```

the path of you exe file and config.exe should be same to avoid database connection issues.
As soon as you run this it will give you a Success message...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a service installer by clicking add installer on the service designer pane. There is a great video on creating and installing windows services using C# on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uM9o8GsO_u4).

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to install your windows service. build your windows service in release mode then copy all the files inside the bin release, then put into a folder

open the command prompt run as administrator go inside that folder then use this command

installutil yourservicename.exe (inside the relese there is a file )

uninstall///

installutil /u yourservicename.exe (inside the relese there is a file )
or 
installutil -u yourservicename.exe (inside the relese there is a file )

cheers

Answer (score -1):

Windows Service:
Step 1:

```
      First step is to add installer
```

Step 2:

Click on your service give the display name

Step 3:

```
     Select Local system
```

Step 4:

```
     Open Developer command prompt
```

Step 5:

```
    InstallUtil your_service_path/Your_service_display_name.exe
```

Step 6:

```
      net start Your_service_display_name
```

here is the link

```
           https://youtu.be/rG3Ts5CrTUA
```